# jsf graphicimage tag not working

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using Primefaces 5.2 and I need to display some images on my webpage.
I am using the GraphicImage tag from primefaces and in the name attribute I am passing the full path of the image, but nothing is getting displayed on the webpage and when I checked the source code of the html page generated , there is RES NOT FOUND value on the source attribute of the img tag.

Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
<title>Add your Experience</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
</h:head>
<body>
<div class="container">
        <p:contentFlow value="#{testBean.images}" var="image">
            <p:graphicImage name="C:/Users/Singh/Desktop/Photos/#{image}"
                styleClass="content" />
            <div class="caption">#{image}</div>
        </p:contentFlow>
        <p:graphicImage name="image/bg.jpg" />
        <h:graphicImage name="C:/Users/Singh/Desktop/Photos/abh.jpg"></h:graphicImage>
    </h:form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you are choosing the wrong attribute, to specify a link you have to choose the `url` attribute

```
<p:graphicImage url="image/bg.jpg" />
<h:graphicImage url="C:/Users/Singh/Desktop/Photos/abh.jpg"></h:graphicImage>
```

for the attribute `name`, In JSF 2.x, you can render above image via “resource library” concept, by adding `resources` folder under `webapp` in your project, and in your case you have to add `images` folder under `resources` and add your image in this folder.

The code will be like that :

```
<h:graphicImage library="images" name="bg.jpg" />
```

Comment: Its working for the images which are in the project but for the images which are outside of the project directory its not working. I think I need to write a servlet

Comment: Which is your server?